# Passing image from modal to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

I have the following application, where I have to upload an image directly from modal to the page.

Note that:

1. The image is already uploaded by the admin to this modal.
2. The images are saved in "static" file in "wwwroot" folder. So, No database is required for this step.

All what I need is when I click in the image in the modal, it should be uploaded to the view. So, I can save it later in the database.

Here is Image Bank Controller

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var webRoot = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var appData = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, "static");
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(appData, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var model = new ImageBankViewModel()
        {
            ImagesListUrls = files.Select(i=>Path.GetFileName(i))
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Upload(ImageBankViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.Image != null)
            {
                
                string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                var path = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "static");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

                var extension = Path.GetExtension(model.Image.FileName);
                var newFileName = model.Type + "-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                using (var filesStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, newFileName + extension), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    model.Image.CopyTo(filesStream);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        ImageBankViewModel modelVM = new ImageBankViewModel()
        {
            Image = model.Image,
            ImagesListUrls = model.ImagesListUrls,
            Type = model.Type
        };

        return RedirectToAction("Index",modelVM);//Unsuccessful Upload , fix invalid model
    }

    public IActionResult CreateStory()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetImagesPartial()
    {
        var webRoot = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var appData = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, "static");
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(appData, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var model = new ImageBankViewModel()
        {
            ImagesListUrls = files.Select(i => Path.GetFileName(i))
        };
        return PartialView("_ImagesBankModal",model);
    }

    public void ImageDelete(string image)
    {

    }
    
      public void SelectImage(string image)
        {
           // Here I want to get the selected image from the modal
        }
    }
}
```

Create Story View

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateStory";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>CreateStory</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label>Pic1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Bank" asp-action="GetImagesPartial" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="sel">Select from image bank</a>
        <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div id="partial"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label>Pic2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark">Select from image bank</button>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#sel').click(function () {
                var route = '@Url.Action("GetImagesPartial", "Bank")';
                $('#partial').load(route);
            });

        });
    </script>

}
```

Modal Partial View

```
@model TestApplication.Models.ViewModels.ImageBankViewModel

<div class="modal-header">
    <h2 class="modal-title">Choose</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @if (Model.ImagesListUrls.Any())
    {
        <table>
            @foreach (var image in Model.ImagesListUrls)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Bank" asp-action="SelectImage" asp-route-image="@image" class="btn btn-light position-absolute" style="right:0">Select</a>
                        <img src="~/static/@image" class="img-thumbnail" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <h5>no images exists...</h5>
    }
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: so.. what is the question, what is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can **store the relative path of the selected picture in an input** and pass them to the action.

The following is an example, you can refer to it.

**Index**

```
<form asp-action="Upload" asp-controller="ImageBank"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label>Pic1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" name="model.Image"/>
        <ul class="selectedpic">
            
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-dark sel">Select from image bank</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 addedimg">
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div id="partial"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var currentsel="";
            $('body').on("click",".sel",function () {
                localStorage.setItem("currentsel",$(this).attr("class"));
                var route = '@Url.Action("GetImagesPartial", "ImageBank")';
                $("#myModal").modal("show");
                $('#partial').load(route);
            });            
            $('body').on("click",".selectbtn",function () {
                var currenttd=$(this).closest("td");
                console.log(currenttd.find("img").attr("src"))
                var classarry=localStorage.getItem("currentsel").split(" ");
                var currentsel="."+classarry[classarry.length-1];
                var currentaddedimg=$(currentsel).closest(".row").find(".addedimg");
                var addsrc=currenttd.find("img").attr("src");
                if(checkisexsist(currentaddedimg,addsrc)){
                    $(currentsel).closest(".row").find(".selectedpic").append("<li>"+addsrc+"</li>");
                    $(currentsel).closest(".row").find(".addedimg").append("<input hidden name='selimages' value='"+addsrc+"'/>");
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                      localStorage.removeItem("currentsel");
                    });
                }else{
                    alert("has selected");
                }
                
            });
            function  checkisexsist(currentaddedimg,addsrc){
                var flag=true;
                $.each(currentaddedimg.find("input[name='selimages']"), function( index, value ) {
                 if($(value).val()==addsrc){
                      flag=false;
                 }
                });
                return flag;
            }
    </script>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(ImageBankViewModel model,List<string> selimages)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.Image != null)
        {
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var path =Path.Combine(webRootPath, "static");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(model.Image.FileName);
            var newFileName = model.Type + "-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            using (var filesStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, newFileName + extension), FileMode.Create))
            {
                model.Image.CopyTo(filesStream);
            }
        }
        if(selimages!=null& selimages.Count != 0)
        {
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var path = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "static");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            selimages.ForEach(m =>
            {
                var newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var extension = "." + m.Split(".")[m.Split(".").Length - 1];
                var oldpath =webRootPath+m.Replace("/", "\\");                      var newpath = Path.Combine(path, newFileName + extension);
                System.IO.File.Copy(oldpath,newpath);
            });
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ImageBankViewModel modelVM = new ImageBankViewModel()
    {
        Image = model.Image,
        ImagesListUrls = model.ImagesListUrls,
        Type = model.Type
    };

    return RedirectToAction("Index", modelVM);//Unsuccessful Upload , fix invalid model
}
```

**_ImagesBankModal**(Only give the modified place)

```
<a class="btn btn-light position-absolute selectbtn">Select</a>
```

**Result**
[image]